# Rails errors in routing roots

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a simple project controller name posts. My routes has :
1. get 'posts'
2. root 'post#index'

But when I am starting the server it is stopping automatically and giving a bunch of error. But once I comment out the line get 'posts' rails server works properly. why is this happening ?

Comment: please share a minimal code and the first few lines of the server error

Comment: > Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/tito/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:275:in `check_part': Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)
 from /home/tito/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:255:in `check_controller_and_action'

Comment: in the routes.rb `get 'your_controller/controller_action'`

Comment: please post your route.rb file

Answer (score 1):

hi @Prabal Kar you are not defining routes correctly, you should have to mention controller action where which an API request should be redirected.

In  particular you should have to repalce your 1 route defination with line given below -:

> get 'posts' => 'posts#index'

where 'posts' is your controller name(in smallcase) and 'index' in your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write it right. You have only controller name, but where is an action?

```
get 'your_controller/controller_action'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it  `resources :posts`

[routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)